# How to print array to csv

Tags: magento-1.9

Hi am trying to export order data in magento 1 to csv

**here is my script**

```
<?php
require_once 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::app();
Mage::app()->getStore()->setId(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
$orderCollection = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection();

$fp = fopen('orders_exported.csv', 'w');

foreach ($orderCollection as $order) {
        $orders['orders'][] = array(
            'id'            => $order->getIncrementId(),
            'store'         => 'magento',
            'status'        => $order->getStatus(),
            'name'          => $order->getCustomerName(),
            'email'         => $order->getCustomerEmail(),
            'telephone'     => $order->getShippingAddress()->getTelephone(),
            'street'        => $order->getShippingAddress()->getStreet(),
            'pincode'       => $order->getShippingAddress()->getPostcode(),
            'city'          => $order->getShippingAddress()->getCity(),
            'weight'        => $order->getWeight(),


        );    

     foreach ($order->getAllItems() as $item) {
       $orders['orders']['items'][] = array(
            'id'            => $order->getIncrementId(),
            'name'          => $item->getName(),
            'sku'           => $item->getSku(),
            'Price'         => $item->getPrice(),
            'Ordered Qty'   => $item->getQtyOrdered(),


        );

    }
    }

echo "<pre>"; print_r($orders);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Please try following way i think it work for you

```
<?php
require_once 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::app();
Mage::app()->getStore()->setId(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
$orderCollection = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection();

$fp = fopen('orders_exported.csv', 'w');

foreach ($orderCollection as $order) {
    $orders['orders'][] = array(
        'id'            => $order->getIncrementId(),
        'store'         => 'magento',
        'status'        => $order->getStatus(),
        'name'          => $order->getCustomerName(),
        'email'         => $order->getCustomerEmail(),
        'telephone'     => $order->getShippingAddress()->getTelephone(),
        'street'        => $order->getShippingAddress()->getStreet(),
        'pincode'       => $order->getShippingAddress()->getPostcode(),
        'city'          => $order->getShippingAddress()->getCity(),
        'weight'        => $order->getWeight(),


    );

    foreach ($order->getAllItems() as $item) {
        $orders['orders']['items'][] = array(
            'id'            => $order->getIncrementId(),
            'name'          => $item->getName(),
            'sku'           => $item->getSku(),
            'Price'         => $item->getPrice(),
            'Ordered Qty'   => $item->getQtyOrdered(),


        );
    }
    fputcsv($fp, $orders['orders'], ",");
}
fclose($fp);

echo "<pre>"; print_r($orders);
```

Comment: i have already found a way to sort this out between this is not working with the way u told if you want i can answer my question

Answer (score 0):

this is just for the help so that others dont put there so much valuable time in to it thankss

```
<?php
    require_once 'app/Mage.php';
    Mage::app();
    Mage::app()->getStore()->setId(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);

    /** @var Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Order_Collection $orderCollection */
    $orderCollection = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection();
    $orders = [];
    $orders[] = [
        'ID',
        'Store',
        'Status',
        'Name',
        'Email',
        'Telephone',
        // 'Street',
        'Pincode',
        'City',
        'Weight',
        'Products'
    ];

    /** @var Mage_Sales_Model_Order $order */
    foreach ($orderCollection as $order) {
        $orderInfo = [
            $order->getIncrementId(),
            'magento',
            $order->getStatus(),
            $order->getCustomerName(),
            $order->getCustomerEmail()
        ];

        if ($order->getIsVirtual()) {
            $orderInfo[] = $order->getBillingAddress()->getTelephone();
            // $orderInfo[] = $order->getBillingAddress()->getStreet();
            $orderInfo[] = $order->getBillingAddress()->getPostcode();
            $orderInfo[] = $order->getBillingAddress()->getPostcode();
        } else {
            $orderInfo[] = $order->getShippingAddress()->getTelephone();
            // $orderInfo[] = $order->getShippingAddress()->getStreet();
            $orderInfo[] = $order->getShippingAddress()->getPostcode();
            $orderInfo[] = $order->getShippingAddress()->getPostcode();
        }

        $orderInfo[] = $order->getWeight();
        $itemsStr = [];
        $orderItems = $order->getAllItems();
        /** @var Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Item $item */
        foreach ($orderItems as $item) {
            $orderItem = [
                $order->getIncrementId(),
                $item->getName(),
                $item->getSku(),
                $item->getPrice(),
                $item->getQtyOrdered()
            ];

            $itemsStr[] = implode('|', $orderItem);
        }

        $orderInfo[] = implode("\n", $itemsStr);
        $orders[] = $orderInfo;


    $fp = fopen('order_export.csv', 'w');

    foreach ($orders as $val) {
        fputcsv($fp, $val);
    }

    fclose($fp);


    }


    print_r($orders);
```